# How to get this number pattern output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print this pattern using javascript.

```
5
3 5
1 3 5
```

So far I've tried a for loop

```js
var n = prompt("Enter the number:"); //n=5
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
      document.write(n + " ")
    } else {
      document.write(n - 2 + " ");
    }
  }
  document.write('<br />');
}
```

but I get this output only

```
5 
3 5 
5 3 5
```

How sould I enhance the code?

Comment: `n is not defined`

Comment: sorry, I just missed it, see now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need a second for-loop to print your pyramid. The basic algorithm works like this:

- check for edge cases once (infinite loop, negative values)
- create a string (str) that is used for the loop
- save current number + " " + str into str and print
- reduce by a predefined distance
- repeat until you reach < 0

Here is a simple implementation to print your pyramid:

```js
function printPyramid(length, distance) {
    
    // check for a distance of 0 => infite loop
    if (distance === 0) return "";

    // check for negeative values
    if (distance < 0) distance = Math.abs(distance);
    if (length < 0) length = Math.abs(length);

    str = "";
    for (let i = length; i > 0; i -= distance) {
        str = i + " " + str;
        console.log(str);
    }
}

printPyramid(5, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a fun little puzzle for me having just learned about generators.

```js
function* patternGenerator(end = 3, num = 0) {
  let iterationCount = 0;
  let pattern = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < end; i += 1) {
    pattern = `${num - iterationCount * 2} ` + pattern;
    iterationCount++;
    yield pattern.trim();
  }
}

for (let value of patternGenerator(3, 5)) {
  document.write(value);
  document.write("<br />");
}
```

[working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqmnkr713p)

Comment: Opps, my bad, fixed.

Comment: again a mistake 

Comment: Oh jeeze, I though the bottom pattern was the expected output. NOW it's fixed.